# Split/Cut Audio file in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio

I have one issue I want to cut/split audio file and get that file after splitting
Like I have a file about 1:28 duration now I want to cut the audio file from 20 sec to 50 sec, I used mp3-cuter but it will generate 20 sec to 50-sec file **but I want to skip these seconds and produce a new file that is not included 20 sec to 50 sec.**

Please let me know if any library which can help to split audio file
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you cut `0-20`sec and `50-lengthoffile`sec and concat them. Now, you can have a file with exact same audio you need.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara thank you. Yeah I am doing now in that way